# How to I load a javascript file using express and node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to load a simple javascript client-side library while using node.js and express.  Any ideas?  See below.

HAML:

```
%script{type: 'text/javascript', src: '/jquery-1.4.3.js'}
%script{type: 'text/javascript', src: '/client.js'}
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/*.js', function(req, res) {
  res.render(req.params + '.js', { layout: false} );
});
```

Error:

Error: Cannot find module 'js'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.0rc4/package/lib/express/view.js:289:46)
    at Object. (/Users/seanbollin/nodemud/app.js:18:7)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.2.6/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:72:27)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.2.6/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:87:10)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.2.6/package/lib/connect/index.js:264:23)
    at Object.bodyDecoder [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.2.6/package/lib/connect/middleware/bodyDecoder.js:54:13)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.2.6/package/lib/connect/index.js:264:23)
    at Object.handle (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.0rc4/package/lib/express/server.js:61:9)

Comment: Does `app.get()` allow wildcards?

Answer (score 4):

use connect's staticProvider http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/staticProvider.html :)